# Setting the coordinate style in the environment of axis

Tags: pgfplots

I change the coordinate of x, errors occur. The x coordinates I want to show are `10^-3, 10^-6, 10^-9, 10^-12`. By now I only write a test. In the test there are only two coordinates. It can compile successfully for 
coordinates `{(0.0001,50e6) (1,33e6)}`; Or
coordinates `{(0.0001,50e6) (10^1,33e6)}`; 
But the pdf generated is wrong.
It would fail to compile if using coordinates `{(0.0001,50e6) (0.0000001,33e6)}`;
[image]
Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}    
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,sci,
sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}},
    ylabel=Population,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar=5pt,% configures `bar shift'
    bar width=9pt,
    nodes near coords,
    point meta=y *10^-7 % the displayed number
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(0.0001,50e6) (0.00001,33e6)};

\legend{Far,Near}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that you need semi logarithmic axes ... differences in between `0.000 1` and `0.000 000 1,` 1000 times or looked from opposite side, negligible small!

Comment: @Zarko Hello. Thanks for your comment. That makes sense for x axis. But the y axis is in the same range. I am not sure how to define for both axis.

Comment: axis can be linear (as you have now: `\begin{axis} ... \end{axis}`), logarithmic (`\begin{logaxis}...\end{logaxis}`) or semi logarithmic for selected axis (`\begin{semilogyaxis} ...\end{semilogyaxis}` or  `\begin{semilogxaxis} ...\end{semilogxaxis}`)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved in the comments.